# Installing google Go in Ubuntu

Tags: installation, programming

Can Google Go be installed on Ubuntu? I want start to test these tools and it will be great if I could.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be installed.
Installation instruction is available at the home page.

http://golang.org/doc/install